# Closed-form expression of a definite integral

Tags: definite-integrals, closed-form, symbolic-computation

Does this definite integral admit a closed-form in terms of elementary functions?

$$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{x}{\left(x^4+1\right) \left(2 x^2-2 \arctan\left(x^2\right)+\pi \right)} \, dx.$$

Comment: Hint: substitute $arctan(x^{2})=u$

Comment: We would get $\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \frac{1}{-4 u+4 \tan (u)+2 \pi } \, du$ (not a closed-form).

Comment: Substitute $v=\frac\pi2-u$ to get $I=\frac14\int^{\frac\pi2}_{0}\frac{dv}{\cot v+v}\approx0.744494.$